# Prove that the sequence $(1-2n) \to -\infty $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Please check my proof and point the mistake

For $M> 0$ there is $K$ such that $n\geq k$ and $1-2n\leq -M$ for $n\geq M_{n}$.

Because $1-2n< -M$ we get $n> \frac{M+1}{2}$.

If we choose $K\geq \frac{M+1}{2}$, we get $n> \frac{M+1}{2}$ such that $1-2n< -M$, therefore the sequence diverge to $-\infty$

Comment: It is correct .

Comment: I tried to edit the best that I can but it is not clear sometimes your wording, in this case I leave unchanged.

Comment: Sorry,My english is so bad -*-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A<0$ given.

take $N=\lfloor \frac{1-A}{2} \rfloor +1$.

then

$\forall n\geq N   \;\;\; n>\frac {1-A}{2}$

$\implies \forall n\geq N \;\; 1-2n<A$

$\implies \lim_{n\to+\infty}(1-2n)=-\infty$

Answer (score 2):

The mistake is here:

> For $M> 0$ there is $K$ such that $n\geq k$ and $1-2n\leq -M$ for $n\geq M_{n}$.

This means nothing. A correct version would be

> For $M>0$, there exists $k$ such that, for all $n\ge k$, it holds $1-2n\leq -M$

In order to prove this, fix $M>0$. The inequality
$$
1-2n\leq -M
$$
is equivalent to
$$
n\geq\frac{M+1}{2}
$$
so you can take $k=(M+1)/2$ or, if your definition requires $k$ to be integer,
$$
k=\left\lceil \frac{M+1}{2} \right\rceil
$$
(where $\lceil x\rceil$ denotes the least integer greater than or equal to $x$).